# Critique: Which of these logos best suits a custom rap song website?

Tags: logo, critique

Rappacy is a company that makes custom Rap songs to their clients, so the main principles on the logo would be:

**SOUND**:  Represented by the headphones and the microphone

**CREATION**: Represented by the “sound wave” that intentionally resembles an ECG wave or “heartbeat” to get the idea of the birth of a new song

**ACCESSIBLE TO EVERYONE/CUSTOM**: The part of “accessible to everyone” can be represented by the circle which can be interpreted as a globe/Earth (anyone can have a rap song). On the other hand, the part of “custom” can be represented by the shape of an head, which represents the fact that any person can have his own song

**SIMPLICITY**: We want the logo to be as simple as possible, but we want also to represent the principles stated above

Based on these four main principles, we have made this short selection of 4 logos:

[image: Logo List]

We would love to know your feedback regarding these 4 samples we've made taking in account the 4 principles.

Regarding the feedback we would like to know which one you liked the most, which one you disliked the most or any suitable adjustment we should make. To sum up, any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Just some feedback from a design noob: 1 and 4 look more "symmetrical" to me, so it's nicer on the eyes. Depending on how the website looks, 1 or 4 would be the better choice. For example, 4 would look better on a "simplistic web 3.0" inspired website whereas 1 would look better with a darker theme.

Also with 4, I would make the entire wave fit inside the circle like it is with 1.

Comment: Same comment.. they're very pedestrian and uninspired in my opinion. I vote for E) none of the above.

Comment: One thing to think about with you logo, is how well it will reproduce at a small size. Some of your lines (especially in 1 and three) are so think that they might begin to disappear if you need to show your logo at a smaller size. Any chance you get to simplify your design, will usually make it stronger.

Comment: .... http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35677/critique-which-of-these-logo-options-best-suits-a-custom-rap-song-website .... I think a bit of history is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First: you do not need to force all sorts of concepts into one logo. It is a bad idea. What you want is a shape that is clear, recognisable and works in all sorts of sizes. You must anyway teach your users what you do, so better make it as simple as possible. After people got the general idea, you want the logo to be instantly recognisable. That often means removing elements.

The earphones looks imbalanced on all of them. You can make them either exactly a perfect circle, or you can "fill in" the gaps that looks uneven.

Or, to be crazy: *skip the earphones entirely*..

- 1 and 4: the "audio stream" heart monitor, and with
  the white and red colour, these connotations are something you definitely do not want! Hospitals, emergency and rap? I think not.
- No. A mic inside a head? Rather try: place the mic vertical. Make the
  head more like #3. *Cut out* the mic from the face. You will then be
  left with mic as negative space. Simple, symmetrical.
- 1. Probably the best idea. But get rid of that heart monitor! Replace it with the audio stream from #3.